# Why it is required to write each byte with 0 before erase in NOR flash?

Tags: memory, embedded, ram, flash-memory

It is written in some sites that for NOR flash, each byte has to be written with 0 before erase. Why it is required to write with 0 before erasing? Erasing the sector change each byte to 1.

Comment: What does the data sheet say? I would go with its recommendations, and not listen to some may-be dubious sites.

Comment: Nothing like that is mentioned in data sheet.

Comment: Then I would not do it. If it were necessary, it would have been mentioned in the data sheet. (Supposed that there is a chapter about erasing and writing at all.)

Comment: Doesn't it rather mean that erase means changing all zeroes to ones? So unless you have written any zeroes, there is nothing to erase.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about memory hardware, not programming. It belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com